# PHP image upload class guidance

Tags: php, image, upload

I am creating a Image upload system for Client for upload screenshots / images. This will be achived via php and html form.I am doing this things kindly tell if I am missing out on anything...

The if-else statements are in order provided.

1. Check if $_POST is set for files and MAX_FILE_SIZE.
2. Check if extension is allowed ( .jpeg / .jpg / .png / .gif are allowed).
3. If extension matches, we check if its a 0 byte file.
4. If its not a 0-byte file, it has to be less that MAX_FILE_SIZE.
5. If its less tan MAX_FILE_SIZE, we check for any [error] in file_upload ([PHP FILE UPLOAD ERRORS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php))
6. After that, we check for mime-types (allowed mime types : image/png, image/jpg, image/gif, image/jpeg)
7. After all above conditions are satisfied, we then check for exif_imagetype.
8. Last case , if all above are satisfied is to check if Image has minimum width (300) and height (100).

If all above 8 conditions are satisfied, we then use **move_uploaded_file** and then recreate the IMAGE using image GD (to remove any malicious code, if any) and show it to user.

Is that the safest way to upload image or AM I missing anything?

I just need safest and most optimal way to upload image without compromising any security (Speed if compromised is fine)

Comment: IMO, `8` should be before `6`. I will tell you my logic. First you check the extension, then you make a finer check with `mimetypes`.

Comment: thanks for your comment @IvankaTodorova apart from that alls fine? Is it bulletproof ?

Comment: Probably the 5th check should be one of the main as well.

Comment: so I move 8 to 6 and 5 to the first check?

Comment: You can take a look at this article, I think you will find it helpful. http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/